# Retrieving image using BitmapFactory - SkImageDecoder null return error

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I'm trying to retrieve an image that I (think) I have saved using a surfaceview in a fragment (nightmare) in Android. Here I try to save an image and list all the images in the directory. I've not absolutely no clue where the directory is (storate/emulated/0 etc). I can never find the images anywhere except listing them like this. Which suggests to me that they probably exist?

```
jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


        // Create an image file name
        File image = null;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        try {
            image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
        File f = new File(path);
        File file[] = f.listFiles();
        Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
        String filename = "";
        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("Files", "FileName "+i+" :" + file[i].getName());
            filename = file[i].getName();
        }

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file[0].getAbsolutePath()+"/"+filename);

        ImageView taken_pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.taken_pic);
        taken_pic.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }
};
```

This just gets me a list of image names and an 'SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null' message. I may have made things worse with the filename string, but even hardcoding in one of the files in the list that is echoed out I get the same results. Should the images exist based on the results of this code? How can I actually get the images again as bitmaps? Is there a better way to do this. I've tried every example I can find and read every topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my now working example of a button that will work with a surfaceview which is displaying the camera to correctly save an image (currently to downloads folder), retrieve it and output it to an imageview (currently "taken_pic").

Not sure exactly where I was going wrong. I think just in several small places. A big issue is the difficulty in debugging this. My phone is not rooted so I think my options with Android Studios Device Monitor were limited. Often you won't see images that have been saved when browsing via a PC explorer. Remove the USB, restart the phone and the files should appear where they should be.

I hope this may be of help to someone.

```
        camera_picture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                captureImage();
            }
        });

        private void captureImage() {
            cam.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }

        rawCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
            }
        };

        /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
        shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
            public void onShutter() {
                Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
            }
        };

        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    File fileb = new     File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "imagename2.jpg");
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(fileb);
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
            }
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");


            String photoPath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/imagename.jpg";
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);

            ImageView taken_pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.taken_pic);
            taken_pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```